# R: Making pivot table with dplyr or reshape2 package

Tags: r, dplyr, reshape, reshape2

I am trying to make simple pivot table in R using `dplyr` or `reshape2` packages as my dataset is too large and R goes out of memory with `sqldf`. The two columns of my dataset that I want to make a pivot table out of is `"Product"` and `"Cust_Id"`. I want to count the number of customer per product. And this is what I got.

```
library(reshape2)
mydata<-read.table("Book1.txt",header=TRUE,fill=TRUE)
mydata.m<-melt(mydata,id=c("Product"),measured=c(Cust_Id))
mydata.d<-dcast(mydata.m,Product~variable,count)
```

It returns

```
Error in UseMethod("group_by_"):
no applicable method for 'group_by_' applied to an object of class "c('integer','numeric')"
```

I have also tried `dplyr` with below code(not sure about the last step though as I did it on the other laptop)

```
library(dplyr)
mydata.df<-tbl_df(mydata)
summarize(mydata.df,Product,Cust_Id=n())
```

I got no error message but a lot of values seems to be missing in the output.
I really appreciate your input. Thanks in advance.

Comment: could you dput() part of your data and share an example of the result you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
library(dplyr)
mydata <- mydata %>%
  group_by(Product) %>%
  summarise(nCustomers = n())
```

Alternatively, if you only want to count unique customers, you can do:

```
library(dplyr)
mydata <- mydata %>%
  group_by(Product) %>%
  summarise(nCustomers = n_distinct(Cust_Id))
```

Answer (score 0):

If this really is a big data set then your best option in the `data.table` package

```
require(data.table)

mydata_data_table = data.table(mydata)

number_customer = mydata_data_table[, .(number_customers = .N), by=Product]
```